# Ionic Framework list scrolling

Tags: ionic-framework

I have my simple application using Ionic Framework.

It looks like :
[image]

Here the list code :

```
 <ion-list show-Reorder="data.showReorder">
        <ion-item class="item-avatar item-icon-right" ng-repeat="band in bands" type="item-text-wrap" href="#/bands/{{auth.profile.name}}/{{band.id}}">
```

My problem is, when I try to scroll the list up and down, it always shows blur on the selected list, and it makes the view when doing scrolls is not smooth enough.

I can solve that blur problem, but I lose the list `ng-click` and `href` capabilities, like

```
 <ion-list show-Reorder="data.showReorder">
        <ion-item class="item-avatar item-icon-right" ng-repeat="band in bands" type="item-text-wrap">
```

How to resolve that blur problem without losing `ng-click` and `href` capabilities, in order to make scrolls are smoother?

Comment: can you provide codepan?

Comment: unfortunately, I can't, because I've never used codepen before, it's just too complicated for me since there was so many integration with my .js file. But I've found an example, here at : http://codepen.io/ionic/pen/JsHjf , it's just same with mine. I want the list works like as if the code href="#/item/{{item.id}}" is deleted from that codepen html.

Comment: Doesn't really solve your solution. But for performance issue, with Ionic framework, you can use `collection-repeat` instead of `ng-repeat`. It loads only the items that are displayed on the screen.

Answer (score 0):

Try using ui-sref instead of href. If this doesn't work create an anchor link inside your ion-item and redirect through it. Hopefully this will solve your problem.